# iOS: Swift: Core Data: Error: +entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I used Core Data for a table view with Swift Language. It can launch successfully, but after clicking Done button in AddView, there is an error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'OneItemCD''

I don't know why. Could anybody help me figure it out? Thanks very much!

Here is the code. There is an add bar button item. Clicking this button transfer to AddViewController. After typing something in the text view and clicking Done button, transfer back to TableViewController.

**TableViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class TableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) -> Int {

    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 0
}

@IBAction func unwindToList(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

    var source: AddViewController = segue.sourceViewController as AddViewController
    source.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    var noteContent: String? = source.contentBody.text

    if noteContent != nil {

        let context = self.fetchedResultsController.managedObjectContext
        let entity = self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.entity
        let newManagedObject = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName(entity.name, inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

        newManagedObject.setValue(noteContent, forKey: "content")

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !context.save(&error) {

            abort()
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }


}


// MARK: - Fetched results controller

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController {
    if _fetchedResultsController != nil {
        return _fetchedResultsController!
        }

        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest()
        // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("OneItemCD", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
        fetchRequest.entity = entity

        // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
        fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 20

        // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "content", ascending: false)
        let sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
        // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
        let aFetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: "Master")
        aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self
        _fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController

        var error: NSError? = nil
        if !_fetchedResultsController!.performFetch(&error) {

            abort()
        }

        return _fetchedResultsController!
}    
var _fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController? = nil

}
```

**AddViewController:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class AddViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var contentBody: UITextView!

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

I put my entire code in github:

https://github.com/snowffer/testTableViewForCoreData

Comment: The error means you don't have a value for the managed object context. Where are you setting this up and passing it to your view controllers, I can't see that code above.

Comment: Yes, I did not assign a value to the context. I'm working on it and will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `var fetchedResultsController`, your `managedObjectContext` is still `nil`.  Therefore, your app crashes when you declare:

```
let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("OneItemCD", inManagedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext)
```

Make sure to set `managedObjectContext` correctly before you call the previous line of code.

**One more thing**:

To use a Swift subclass of `OneItemCD` with your Core Data model, prefix the class name in the Class field of the model entity inspector with the name of your module, just like this: "testTableViewCoreData.OneItemCD" (See more about Core Data and namespaces [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html)).

Comment: Do you mean I need to rename my Core Data module file from OneItemCD to testTableViewCoreData.OneItemCD?

Comment: Click on the link I provided in my answer and go to the bottom of the page. The picture will show you how to name your entity class in order for Core Data to work with your OneItemCD.swift file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I finally fixed my issue and yes about the "One more thing". That's an issue I didn't notice.